# How to create EF migration classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I seem to be having a hard time finding the information I need to implement EF Core. I've read a lot of articles, and watched videos such as [Getting Started with Entity Framework Core [1 of 5]](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Entity-Framework-Core-101/Getting-Started-with-Entity-Framework-Core?term=entity%20framework%20core%20migration&lang-en=true). But none of these articles and videos assume a Razor Pages project created with the latest version of Visual Studio (16.3.6).

I'm much prefer (and am already familiar with) database first, but Microsoft has decided we need to be code first.

So I manually created my entity classes and ran the `Add-Migration` command. (Note that *00000000000000_CreateIdentitySchema.cs* was created by Visual Studio when I created the project.)

[image]

It runs successfully but creates an empty `Migration` class.

```
public partial class InitialTaskClasses : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {

    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {

    }
}
```

Is there anyway to have it incorporate my entity classes into the migration?

*Note that I've already done an `update-database` command, which added the entity classes to my database.

Comment: @Herohtar: `ApplicationDbContext`, which derives from `IdentityDbContext`, has an empty constructor but no other methods or properties.

Comment: That's your problem. The migrations are created based on what's defined in your DbContext. If that's empty, the migrations will be too.

Comment: Please add the code inside your dbcontext files.

Comment: @Herohtar: Well, that's great. But my question how to get it working. I have no idea what I should enter there. Also migrations seemed to work fine for the entity classes, and they don't appear in the DBContext class either.

Comment: @nurdyguy: Can you be more specific? Which files?

Comment: I recommend following through [Getting Started with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/?tabs=netcore-cli). It very plainly explains how to create the necessary components.

Comment: There is also [Razor Pages with Entity Framework Core in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Your `ApplicationDbContext.cs` file.  The `add-migration` command uses that file to build out the `up` and `down` functions.  You need to add the models in question there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public DbSet<Area> Area{ get; set; }
public DbSet<Goal> Goal{ get; set; }
public DbSet<Task> Task{ get; set; }
```

This should go as properties inside your ApplicationDbContext